# What does the ^ operator do in c++

Tags: c++, c, operators

I came across the ^ operator the other day and I have no idea what it does. For some odd reason, Google searching it didn't work and I couldn't find it here on Stackoverflow either. Could someone explain what this operator is and how it is used. I have a hunch that it is the XOR operator.

Comment: good hunch. Why didn't you google it?

Comment: Just thought of that. I feel stupid.

Comment: You are right, it is the bitwise XOR. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: The duplicate everyone is selecting is wrong.

Comment: @juanchopanza - yeah, that's my fault. Sorry... clicked in the wrong spot.

Comment: By the way, since you are asking about uses, it is widely used in encryption algorithms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your hunch is correct. It is indeed the (bitwise) XOR operator.

See [Bitwise operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Bitwise_operators).

Answer (score 1):

It is the XOR operator.  An example: 0101 ^ 0110 = 0011